# User role for Firestore manage in Google cloud

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I can't figure it out which role/s do I need to have on one of my client's Google Cloud Platform, to do the following:
- Connect and Manage a Firestore database to their Firebase app.
- Use the Google Cloud Firestore API from an external app.

There are so many roles... Any help? :) 
I have already Firebase Analytics Admin but when I tried to access the Firestore through Firebase I get the message "To manage Cloud Firestore, ask a project owner for the necessary permissions".

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Firebase product-category predefined roles [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/roles-predefined-category), the only role that has full read/write access to Cloud Firestore is:

```
Firebase Develop Admin - roles/firebase.developAdmin
```

Regarding the access to the API, the app will be able to access it using either a Firebase Authentication ID token or a Google Identity OAuth 2.0 token as per referenced on this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api).

In order to set up Firebase Auth, [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) might be of help and for OAuth check [this link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).